# Scala-Z3: How to perform member access on objects

Tags: scala, z3

I have defined the following circle Sort in Scala with the java API:
(where `ctx` is a Z3-Context)

```scala
val circleConstructor = ctx.mkConstructor(
    "Circle",
    "Circle",
    Array("x", "y", "r"),
    Array(ctx.mkRealSort, ctx.mkRealSort, ctx.mkRealSort),
    null)

val circleSort: DatatypeSort = ctx.mkDatatypeSort(
    ctx.mkSymbol("Circle"), Array(circleConstructor))

val getX: FuncDecl = circleSort.getAccessors()(0)(0)

val constCirlce: FuncDecl = ctx.mkConstDecl("C", circleSort)
```

How do I go about accessing the `x` member of the circle `C`?

I have tried using `ctx.mkApp` with the `getX` function, but can't figure out how to reference the `C` constant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out.
To access the circle constant, you simply use the variable defined in your code like this:

```
val A = ctx.mkMul(ctx.mkApp(getX, constCirlce).asInstanceOf[ArithExpr])
```

The `.asInstanceOf[ArithExpr]` is for casting the result of `mkApp` to an `ArithExpr`, as `mkMul` expects an `Expr`.
I don't know how to avoid this explicit cast.